# Items.Count = 0 in SelectionChanged when there are items

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, datatemplate

I want to display some *custom content* (using datatemplate) on button click:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="content" />
<Button Content="Test" Click="button_Click" />
```

Button shows/hides content like this

```
VM _vm = new VM();
void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
     content.Content = content.Content == null ? _vm : null;
```

Here is datatemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM}">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Event handler:

```
void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) =>
    Title = "Items: " + ((ListBox)sender).Items.Count;
```

Viewmodel:

```
public class VM
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; } = new List<Item> { new Item(), new Item(), new Item() };
}
public class Item
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

**The problem**: when datatemplate is unloaded then `SelectionChanged` for `ListBox` event is rised with no items.

I do not want this event. I don't want to see "Items: 0" after selecting something and unloading datatemplate.

[image]

**Question**: what is happening and how can I prevent this from happening?

---

Note: this is very short and simplified MCVE, i.e. not everything is pretty, though there are key points: datatemplate with `ListBox` inside, which uses `IsSelected` binding and I need to get rid from that `SelectionChanged` event at unloading.

Call stack:

[image]

Comment: do you have an event that's clearing the item...and another one adding the list...and this might be happening in between?

Comment: `listBox_SelectionChanged` when you unload the list this event is fired, becouse slection actualy changed, Check item count there, and if it is 0 set the title to default

Comment: @Ctznkane525, complete code is shown.

Comment: Makes sense.  When unloaded, the binding is disconnected, and the items source goes to empty.  If there are no items, there can be no selected item.  If there was a selection before, it will be cleared.  That's a change: the selection goes from something to nothing.  It's working exactly as designed.

Comment: @MikeStrobel, event is not rised If I remove binding to `IsSelected`. It's not consistent.

Comment: As long as you select an item before clicking the button, the event should be raised.

Comment: @MikeStrobel, correct, selecting item in the view indeed consistently rises event. Hmm.. Still my question is how to prevent this event from happening? Or what should I check for in event handler to distinguish between "Items = 0 set by viewmodel" and "Items = 0 set by disconnecting source upon unloading"?

Comment: You can't prevent the event from happening.  What do you need the event for?  Instead of using that event, it's usually better to bind the `SelectedItem` to a property on your view model.  It can't update the `SelectedItem` if the template has been unloaded, so you won't have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working exactly as designed.  You made a selection by clicking an item in the list box.  When the template is unloaded, the `ItemsSource` binding is disconnected, and the items source becomes empty.  At that point, the current selection is no longer valid (the item doesn't exist in the items source), so the selection is cleared.  That's a selection change: the selection went from something to nothing.  The event is *expected* to be raised under these circumstances.

It's rarely necessary to subscribe to `SelectionChanged`.  It's usually better to bind the `SelectedItem` to a property on your view model.  Whenever the selection changes, that property will be updated.  Instead of responding to the `SelectionChanged` event, you can respond to that property changing.

This approach nicely avoids the issue you're seeing.  Once the template is unloaded, the `SelectedItem` binding will be disconnected, so your view model won't be updated anymore.  Consequently, you won't see that final change when the selection is cleared.

---

#### Alternate solution for multiple selections

If your `ListBox` supports multiple selections, you can continue subscribing to `SelectionChanged`.  However, don't query `listBoxItems`; instead, scan through `_vm.Items` and see which items have `IsSelected` set to `true`.  That should tell you the actual selection, and the results should not be affected by the template being unloaded.

You can also determine that the template was unloaded by checking whether `(sender as ListBox)?.ItemsSource` is null in your handler.  However, this should not be necessary.

Comment: I am having multi-item selection, therefore `IsSelected` binding. So I have to stick to `SelectionChanged` event unless I want to create a mess in viewmodel (e.g. passing collection instance to every item and calling some method from within setter of `IsSelected`). I'll upvote the answer the answer for correct part of as to "why" it happens, but that doesn't solves my problem .. yet.

Comment: Clever idea, though it won't really work for me. I didn't put all details to keep question short, but virtual listbox in datatemplate has issues and I am using `SelectionChanged` event to synchronize `IsSelected` for those items what are outside of screen (doesn't have container = bindng doesn't update). In other words, I can't use `_vm.Items`. Also, `DataContext` is not `null` when event is rised, you can try it for yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I meant you could check `ItemsSource` for null.  Answer updated.

Comment: Great, it seems exactly what I need. Checking for `ItemsSource` is not binding anymore was something I haven't though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is occurring because you are always overwriting the content:

```
VM _vm = new VM();
void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
     content.Content = content.Content == null ? _vm : null;
```

Change it to this so the list only gets assigned once, so it only gets assigned once.

```
void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (content.Content == null )
    {
        content.Content = _vm; 

        // I also recommend you add the event handler for the ListBox here so it's not fired until you have content.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `listBox_SelectionChanged` when you unload the list this event is fired, because section actually changed, Check item count there, and if it is 0 set the title to default.

```cs
void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) =>
Title = (((ListBox)sender).Items.Count > 0)? "Items: " + ((ListBox)sender).Items.Count: "Your title";
```

Comment: Good idea, but there is a problem with this solution: if list become empty (ObservableCollection, INotifyPropertyChanged, blablabla), event is still rising. How to distinguish between unloading datatemplate and deleting last item?